# How to resize a jTextField using the Swing GUI designer

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

For some reason, when I try to use the following code,

Java Code:

```
idiomText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)width, 24));
```

I can't change the width of the text box, but I can change the height. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong??

If you need more details please let me know

I am using the drag and drop swing gui designer

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) The size of a text field is best specified by the number of columns and font size. *"I am using the drag and drop swing gui designer"* My condolences. We typically only recommend them for people who already understand layouts and component sizing.

Comment: I am definitely a newbie, and although I've gotten a pretty good handle on the GUI builder, there are MANY things that I don't know. I appreciate your response. Is there any alternative you would recommend?

Comment: What layout manager are you using?

Comment: I believe group layout. I am using the netbeans IDE gui builder

Comment: `JTextField#setColumns`

Comment: not sure why the moderators here can destroy a thought process that was going well. If I needed to most that chat I would've. no need to delete it

Comment: @Gary I can re add it if you want. But I think we already established null layout isnt the way to go haha

Comment: My apologies. Im just VERY frustrated. This seems like something that would have a simple solution, yet I've been working on it all day and just can't do it

Comment: i can make y change like it's nothing. x will not change no matter what I put in it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that helps: (It talks about problems with setting a components size: It helped me quite a bit a while back)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/problems.html

**EDIT:**

Another way you can do it is the

```
setSize(int width, int height); method // although it doesn't give you much leeway.
```

But the layout must be set to null in order for this method to work.

```
setLayout(null);
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually read that earlier and had trouble making sense of it. Since I am using a GUI builder(the netbeans IDE), can I edit the size of components if I want to? This article doesn't quite answer that question

Comment: Thank you. I've seen this answer as well. May I ask how I can set the layout null?

Comment: This is for a homework assignment by the way. I am assigned to, upon the press of a button, empty a textfield and resize it's width randomly

Comment: double width=(Math.random()+30)*12;   This is what width equals

Comment: Yeah. Paste that into the setSize Parameters

Comment: setLayout(null);
  idiomText.setSize((int)(Math.random()+30)*12, 30);

Comment: setLayout(null);
  idiomText.setSize((int)(Math.random()+30)*12, 30);

Comment: that's all I've added. If you need anything specific please ask. Thanks for all your help so far by the way

Comment: `null` layouts are never the answer. Since `revalidate` calls `invalidate` and `validate` and are intended to be used as part of the layout management API, it's pointless in calling it if you're going to use `null` layouts

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Yeah they arent. PreferredSize and pack() is the way to go....but the first attempt was a fail and this method is usually " recommended to people who know how to use layouts and such" -Andrew

Comment: Based on testing it yeah null layouts don't work. Do you have any alternatives?

Comment: @Gary i would suggest PrefferedSize() and pack() and revalidate()

Comment: `JTextField` actually provides a method by which you can modify the "preferred" size in a platform independent manner, but because `GroupLayout` does some "interesting" things, it may not work, best to either modify the properties of the layout or using a different layout manager

Comment: @Gary I'd recommend a different layout manager and maybe have a look at `JTextField#setColumns`